# Is it possible to avoid the "AS" parameter when counting total rows of a mysql table? (php)

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Now I use this code to count the total rows of a table:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM MyTable";
$result = mysqli->query($sql);
$numberOfRows = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
$numberOfRows = $numberOfRows->Total;
```

I've tried to dump different results that I get when I don't use the "AS" parameter in the query and searched around in the internet about it, but despite the many examples I've found none of them shows the code to retrieve directly the result without the "AS" paramenter.

...

From the answers and comments received I've tried these two code blocks that give the expected result:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable";
$result = mysqli->query($sql);
```

And then:
With fetch array:

```
$numberOfRows = $result->fetch_array($result);
$numberOfRows = $numberOfRows[0];
```

With fetch assoc:

```
$numberOfRows = $result->fetch_assoc($result);
$numberOfRows = $numberOfRows["COUNT(0)"];
```

Performance wise I've found the fetch array works slightly better (tried without opcode).

Comment: Did you try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable`?

Comment: If you use [`mysqli_fetch_row($result)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) instead of `mysqli_fetch_object($result);` you get [`an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero).`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php). So then with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable` you can use `$numberOfRows[0]`

Comment: It's possible, you'll just have a column called COUNT(*) when you return an associative array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use `AS` to assign an alias, the name of the column in the output will be `COUNT(*)`. You should then be able to retrieve it with:

```
$numberOfRows = $numberOfRows->{"COUNT(*)"}
```